# 4NT like functions in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell and trying to make the switch from 4NT. I have read the opinion on many people doing the same and seem to be happy but I wanted to ask if anyone has come across any PowerShell developed functionality similar to these 4NT functions:

LIST

SELECT

FFIND

I will miss the SELECT and FFIND the most.

SELECT could work with alias to easily select multiple files of different types using the space bar and then automatically delete/copy/etc them very quickly without having to over type or load a GUI app.

```
ex. Typing my alias "SD" this window would appear and I could easily tick several files and hit enter to automatically delete them. Very handy when you need to delete many files among a larger set of files you do not want to delete.
```

See Picture:  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/c7837d04-70f1-4f25-8f85-e773bdcb35da

FFIND was just a very nifty, and FAST, search for text in files utility that made finding anything super quick whether it be C# code, WEB code, txt files, SQL code, or some word or phrase in a document.

Answer (score 1):

I think this particular way is only supported in V3 but ... in PowerShell V3 you can do this easily:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\temp | Out-GridView -PassThru | Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

or if you want to get pithy (and only list files - not dirs - also a V3 feature)

```
ls c:\temp -af | ogv -passthru | ri -wh
```